# Page navigates till last page and stays on last page without breaking the loop using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, pagination

I can paginate till last page but it continues staying on last page

The next button in the last page is enabled and clickable. When the count reaches to total page count the loop has to exit

For some reason it keeps staying on the last page, and I have tried several different methods to catch the error. Its not exiting when the page reaches last page .Next button is visible and present on the page .

int m = 1;

```
while (true) {
    WebElement source_next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='nxt']"));
    WebDriverWait s = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25000);
    s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(source_next));
    action.moveToElement(source_next).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", source_next);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement modalcontent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']"));
    WebElement ignore_yes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='modal-btn-si']"));
    if ((modalcontent != null) && (modalcontent.isDisplayed())) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ignore_yes);
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PageLoadTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    m = m + 1;
    System.out.println(m);
    if (m == pgcount) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your last lines be

```
System.out.println(m);
if(m >= pgcount) //or > ...but don't think so
{
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in java first page is page 0,second page is page 1 etc...
So the condition in the last if statement should me:

```
m==pgcount-1;
```